# X not showing my contacts even after enabling Sync contacts option

Tags: contacts, twitter

That's about it. The feature is found in Privacy and safety -> Discoverability and contacts from X settings. Sync contacts is on but no contacts are shown. I appreciate help.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but has the Contacts permission been allowed from the Android Settings?

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, it's been allowed.

Comment: Try navigating to `chrome://sync-internals` and tapping `get updates`?

Comment: @Arctiic Thanks. I get a "Trigger GetUpdates" button there but nothing happens when I tap it.

Comment: Btw, I mostly use an X app that I installed on my phone, not through Chrome.